# before executing script.sh, Check script.sh running or not, if its running kill and continue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

CMD# bash script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PRE_CHECK=$0

PROCESS_ID=`ps -ef | grep "$PRE_CHECK" | egrep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'`

[[ ! -z $PROCESS_ID ]] && kill -9 $PROCESS_ID

echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
```

Comment: while executing, it killing present one too

Answer (score 0):

In order to know this, you need to know your own process ID. This is stored in the variable `$$`, so you need to kill all PIDs, except for that one.